# How do you fix resolution with AMD integrated GPU cards on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amd-ryzen

I'm looking into dualbooting between Ubuntu and Windows 10 for emulation. However, the system kind of scares me off whenever I try it since I always get very low resolution, around 640xsomething and haven't found any decent solutions as of yet. My monitor is VGA and can reach 1440x900.

- Ryzen 5 3400g
- 2x4 GB RAM
- Radeon Vega 11

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 the latest, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Is there a better and easier version I'm not aware of?

Comment: How do you try it? It should work well enough with this GPU. Also you can try 20.10.

Comment: What's the difference from 20.10 to 20.04? I tried amd-gpu pro but couldn't get it to work

Comment: There is no much difference. If you install 20.04.1 and run install updates, you'll have the 5.8 kernel that supports this GPU better. But you didn't answer how you are trying it. If it is a Virtual machine, it is a different story.

Comment: I set up a bootable flash drive, separated 20 gb for ubuntu on my ssd and tried installing it through the flash drive. It boots at 640x400 and I didn't manage to get amdgpu pro to work in it

Comment: You don't need amdgpu pro to get the resolution. Install the system, then install upadtes, then reboot. It should work OK, unless you are using some bad adapter with your monitor cable.

Comment: I did mention it's a VGA monitor. Maybe that is the problem? When I try setting it up on my tv screen which has hdmi, it works with no problem

Comment: Maybe you'll need to set resolution manually using xrandr. It is not related to any drivers.

Comment: Okay, I'm on ubuntu installation right now and using the try out ubuntu option. I tried using xrandr and it said I couldn't set it to 1440x900, which is my only monitor's maximum resolution. I tried 1024x576 as well and got nothing. Any ideas? I can't install because I can't see the buttons unless I plug my case with my tv screen

Comment: You'll need to create a custom resolution if your monitor is not detected properly. Also you need to install the system and upgrade kernel first.

Comment: @LeoAndro If you want to edit system details *before* you install Ubuntu to your HDD, you could use your current Ubuntu-on-USB to create [a persistent live USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) that you can edit.